# How to adjust Textbox in New Form Item using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I'm new with SharePoint 2013 Development and I'm really enjoying it. But I did encounter a bump with creating new forms ins SharePoint Designer.

I have a simple custom list and I need to have fields about State and Zip Code. Now when I created the new form, the textbox (single line of text column type) is a bit long and I need make it smaller. The only catch is that I need to do it in JQuery? Below is what I have.

[image]

this is what I have for my SharePoint tags and JavaScript.

```
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff8{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="State" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff8',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@State')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff8description{$Pos}" FieldName="State" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>

                    <td width="50px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Zip Code</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Zip_x0020_Code" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Zip_x0020_Code')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="Zip_x0020_Code" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>

<script>
    $("State").css("width", 100);
    $("Zip Code").css("width", 100);
</script>
```

Hope you guys can help me out. Thank you.

**RESOLVED!**

I figured it out. Here is what I used for those like me struggling.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('input[title="State"]').css("width","100px");
        $('input[title="Zip Code"]').css("width","100px");
    }
);
```

Comment: Did you try style attribute inside the SharePoint:FormField tag?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Here is what I used for those like me struggling.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[title="State"]').css("width","100px");
    $('input[title="Zip Code"]').css("width","100px");
});
```